# Wii Swapforce missing entire area?

Tags: ps3, nintendo-wii, skylanders-swap-force

My husband has the swapforce game for the PS3 and my son and nephews have it for the wii.  My husband has areas that the wii doesn't have.

For example when you jump (forgive me, I am a MOM not a swapforce player) up the steps that look like mushrooms to the top of the tree, next to the path towards Master Eon's head.. If you get to the top of the tree, there is supposedly a 'jump pad" that sends you down to the pool and into a bonus world in woodburrow where you are up in the air collecting coins.

This area is always there on the ps3 version but it has never been there on the wii game.

We DO have the dark edition game for the wii and the regular for the ps3.  IS anyone else having this issue?  The area is absolutely supposed to be there according to the walkthough guide.  Just wondering why it isn't.

Comment: The guide can be wrong.  The guide indicates its for what systems?